# ARM MMU disabled 4KB

Tags: assembly, arm, mmu

I want the MMU disabled during a boot program (bare metal) for an ARMv7 architecture.
Reading the ARM ARM I stumbled onto this.

"When the MMU is disabled, an instruction can be fetched if one of the following conditions is met:

• The instruction is in the same 4KB block of memory (aligned to 4KB) as an instruction that is
required by a simple sequential execution of the program, or is in the 4KB block of memory
immediately following such a block.

• The instruction is in the same 4KB block of memory (aligned to 4KB) from which an instruction has
previously been required by a simple sequential execution of the program with the MMU disabled,
or is in the 4KB block immediately following such a block."

Anyone up to decrypting and explain to me how I can ensure that instructions are within 4KB/8KB next to each other? (That is how I understand the statements..)

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this means that you may not jump more than (8 KiB minus current page offset) forward, and not backwards into a previous 4 KiB page. Basically: linear program flow is okay, as are forward jumps by about 4 KiB; backward jumps (and loops) are only okay if they are guaranteed to not cross a page.

You can probably teach your C compiler to use a short-jumps model, if you use C; if you use assembly directly this is fairly easy to do. Also use a linker script or directly convert to a binary output format to ensure that the memory addresses you get loaded at match those you *think* you are loaded at during development.

Many assemblers support doing offset calculations for jumps. You could also generate a link map of all symbols, then analyse that your jumps are not too large.

Of course, looking at how the BSDs and Linux do this might prove to be useful. I guess they just enable the MMU quickly and use few and hand-written code until then.

Comment: I will look into the short-jumps model etc as soon as I understand the issue I am trying to solve. It is hard to understand the restrictions from the text alone. @dwelch dwelch may be on the right track

Comment: Ah yes, he goes onto it from a totally separate angle: the CPU imposes constraints on the memory (controller) by prefetching and the likes, so the system designer must make their system capable of supporting this operation mode of the CPU. Makes sense. It’s a different reading from the one I did, but thanks to the context, it does sound plausible.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the rest of the context then you see that

> These accesses can be caused by speculative instruction fetches, regardless 
>   of whether the prefetched instruction is committed for
>   execution.
>
> Note
>   To ensure architectural compliance, software must ensure that both of 
>   the following apply:
>
> instructions that will be executed when an MMU is disabled are 
>   located in 4KB blocks of the address space that contain only memory
>   that is tolerant to speculative accesses
>
> each 4KB block of the address space that immediately follows 
>   a 4KB block that holds instructions that will be executed when an MMU is
>   disabled also contains only memory which is tolerant to speculative
>   accesses.

All they are saying is where the branch predictors are likely to pull instructions, whether used or not.  So if you have the MMU off and you are executing near the end of your ram, and your memory controller will not tolerate reads (fetches) past the end of that ram.  then you may have problems.   Either dont run your code that close or change your memory controller to be more tolerant, or turn the mmu on and tolerate its nuances, whatever they may be.  (with the mmu on you could more easily map that next block to some other ram knowing that you wont actually be executing there, but just as a pad for the branch predictor fetches).

How do you insure this?  simple tell your linker not to put code there and it will warn and/or fail if .text gets too close.

Comment: I actually dont understand :-(. My mini system consists of 64KB of ROM (where my program is run) and only 16KB of sram. Branch prediction is off. Is it possible to turn off prefeching? It is a somewhat hard text to read...

Comment: Do you _need_ to turn off prefetching, that is? If your ROM and SRAM tolerate speculative accesses, you don’t need to do anything. I think the issues at hand here are that the CPU can (try to) read from addresses that are backed by I/O space, or not by memory at all, and while the MMU is disabled, the normal page fault mechanism isn’t used, so this could bring the system into an abnormal state. Maybe enabling the MMU early (within the first 4K or 8K of your ROM) is possible?

Comment: Just read the manual, the problem has to do with speculative reads which are in the neighborhood of the code being run, and if your memory system cannot tolerate those reads, then your system will fail.  Ideally this is a chip design problem not a software problem, but that depends on the silicon engineers.  You can certainly test it or just keep your code that far away from memory spaces that are not happy.  Typically you would have stack at the top end of ram and probably data at the top end of rom so it normally wouldnt be a problem.

Comment: I will continue as there "should be no problem", but leave the question as unanswered. Thanks for the useful comments!

Comment: the arm docs answer your question, I dont understand the problem.